# Leaflet draw following lines on custom map layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, drawing

How to draw lines in Leaflet map who following marked mountain routes?
[Example image](https://i.imgur.com/sIjuGAL.png)

Tried all plugins, but they don't follow routes. The goal is a route planner similar to OutdoorActive.

Comment: Did you try [Polyline](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline)?

Comment: There are hundreds of trails, thousands of kilometers long.
It cannot be used.

Comment: You may try to find data of your routes online. i.e.: OpenStreetMap allows to download it https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data and you can extract your routes from there.